# Open subset of a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I have to prove that an open subset of a regular Surface is also a regular Surface
I have no clue on How to start that demonstration or what Path to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the fact that if you have an atlas $\mathcal{U}$ on your original surface, say $S$, then $\mathcal U':=\lbrace V\cap U \: : \: V\in\mathcal U \rbrace $ is an atlas on the open subset $U\subseteq S$.